# getting elements value from a row that contains Edit button

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have a below peice of code. Its a dynamic table based on the output of ${listStores}. Each Row has a Edit Button at the last cell. On Click of it i want to get the StoreId which is  a hidden element against that corresponding row.

```
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listOpenStores}" var="store">
            <tr>
                <td class="collapsing">
                    <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox"> <label></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="at-liststore-storeid-hidden" > 
                    <div class="ui input">
                        <input type="text" value="${store.storeId}">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>${store.storeName}</td>
                <td>${store.storeURL}</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="at-store-edit-btn" class="ui primary icon button"><i class="pencil icon"></i></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>            
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Did you attempt to solve this yourself? How far did you go? Show us your code.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique on document context. Your rendered HTML markup is not valid$

Comment: i tried using var elem = $(this).parent().parent(); but cannot get through

Comment: @user3817659 Put your failing attempt in question with enough context (as how you call it) to give some sense to it

Comment: ok.. Agreed even if the button id is made unique that sure isnt the issue here..

Comment: try this:
$(this).parent().siblings('#at-liststore-storeid-hidden').find('input').val();

Comment: `that sure isnt the issue here` It could be so what?! If you prefer to use invalid HTML markup, who cares?!

Comment: @Jain : That Worked ! Thanks. Will try it for more rows

Comment: @A.Wolff yes i'm agree with you but i'm not manipulating html given here. And i'll provide another way to do this, would you like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('#at-liststore-storeid-hidden').find('input').val();
```

But repeating to same id is invalid 
So you can also try this without id

```
 $(this).parent().prev().eq(2).find('input').val();
```

Comment: Hey, What could have been a better way to achieve this kind of functionality ? If i wanted to make the Id's Unique, is it a better idea to append storeid dynamically with id or if i want to reference this with name attribute ?

Comment: @above it mainly depends on your need, if your page is not so big or no ids is in hundreds then store dynamic ids is best way to do this task becoz search of id in jquery is fastest compare to anyother method otherwise using common class is also good idea.